# Setting up VPN on win2k3

Tags: windows-server-2003, vpn, internet, file-sharing

Recently moved local server to a datacenter. It is used for small file storage, database and thats about it.

I am trying to setup VPN there, which I have never done.

I tried setting it up while following this tutorial: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/configure-a-windows-server-2003-vpn-on-the-server-side/5805260
Worked out good but I do not need NAT server there.

Then I also tried setting up only VPN Server (Remote Access option). Worked good but one thing. While client is connected, it looses internet connection.

Two questions from here.

1. If VPN&NAT setup is used, does that mean client is using internet connection through VPN Server?
2. How can client keep internet connection while connected to VPN Server (which is setup as Remote Access)?

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting in the Windows VPN setup that says something about using the gateway on the remote server.  If you uncheck this it will only tunnel traffic for the remote subnet and not the rest of the internet connection.

The answer is the same as this question:
[windows pptp vpn client *do not* use default gateway on remote network](https://serverfault.com/questions/71590/windows-pptp-vpn-client-do-not-use-default-gateway-on-remote-network)

Comment: For this to work would I have to use VPN&NAT setup or only VPN Setup?

Comment: This only refers to the VPN AFAIK.  NAT Shouldn't come into play here.